# catch() gives "URI is null" for my HTTPs request

Tags: java, json, exception, https, uri

I'm trying to use an HTTPS request to get a JSON object from this URI: "https://api.agify.io/?name=." I hope to add specifications as to which name I'd want to pull information for and get the average age for that name. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it working and my `catch()` is giving `uri is null.` Seems like I've tried anything so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
package com.fisla.apitest;

import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create scanner variable
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a name:");

        String name = in.nextLine();

        try {

            //Setup newBuilder and specify URI
            HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI("https://api.agify.io/?name=" + name));

            //Create the HTTP request and specify its function
            HttpRequest request;
            request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .GET()
                    .build();

            System.out.print(request);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way

```java
try {

    //Create the HTTP request and specify its function
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                           .newBuilder(new URI("https://api.agify.io/?name=" + name));

    System.out.print(request);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Because when you do just `HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI("https://api.agify.io/?name=" + name));` you do not store any reference to that builder and later in your example you create another one without URI specified.